# Simulating Map-reduce using Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, simulation, cloudera

I want to use cloudera to simulate Hadoop job on a single machine (of course with many VMs). I have 2 question
1) Can I change the replication policy of HDFS in cloudera?
2) Can I see cpu usage of each VMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can change data replication policy by changing "ReplicationTargetChooser.java".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hadoop fs -setrep`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/hdfs_shell.html#setrep) to change the replication factor on any file. You can also change the default replication factor by modifying `hdfs-site.xml` by adding the following:
     `<property>
     <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>2</value>
     </property>`

You'll have to log into each box and use `top` to see the cpu usage of each VM. There is nothing out of the box in Hadoop that lets you see this.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to change the factor I want to change the policy of data placement. I want to say that each replica reside on which node. like this  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-385.

Comment: You've asked this before -- it's not possible. Perhaps you should try asking about what you are actually trying to do so we can suggest the right way of doing it.

Comment: But in the above link it seems to be solved! I want to change the data replica location to see how energy usage changes.